# How to show active tab on page load jQuery Scrolltabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs, scrollable, jquery-scrollable

I have used [jQuery Scrolltabs](http://joshreed.github.io/jQuery-ScrollTabs/) which renders scrollable tabs, which works fine. But I am not able to show the active tab selected on page load.

I have around 30 tabs and want to show 25th tab selected. I did go through the documentation but not able to find the solution. Any idea how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. I solved it by triggering click to the particular li.

for example : -

```
<li id="test1" role="presentation" rel="1" class="scroll_tab_first" style="display: inline-block; zoom: 1; user-select: none;">1</li>
<li id="test2" role="presentation" rel="2" class="" style="display: inline-block; zoom: 1; user-select: none;">2</li>
<li id="test3" role="presentation" rel="3" class="" style="display: inline-block; zoom: 1; user-select: none;">3</li>
<li id="test4" role="presentation" rel="4" class="" style="display: inline-block; zoom: 1; user-select: none;">4</li>
<li id="test5" role="presentation" rel="5" class="" style="display: inline-block; zoom: 1; user-select: none;">5</li>
```

for showing last *'li'* i used

```
$('#test5').trigger('click');
```